# Plotting a function in R

Tags: r, matlab, data-visualization

I'm doing QDA on my data and need to plot a decision boundary in `R` ,or `MATLAB`, which looks like the function below.

`0.651 - 0.728(x_1) - 0.552(x_2) - 0.006(x_1 * x_2) - 0.071(x_1)^2 +.170 (x_2)^2 = 0`

Can anyone help me? I've been search the interwebs and can't seem to find the solution.

Comment: it shouldn't be three-dimensional. It should look like a plot from https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat557/book/export/html/35 2nd one from the bottom

Comment: Maybe I'll try contours

Answer (score 3, accepted):

R doesn't have a function to plot an implicit function like this, but you can fake it pretty well with a contour plot. Assuming you want to plot over the region [0,1]^2 (which can easily be changed), you want some code like this:

```
#f is your function
f <- function (x_1, x_2) 0.651 - 0.728 * x_1 - 0.552 * x_2 - 0.006 * x_1 * x_2 - 0.071 * x_1^2 +.170 * x_2^2

#length=1000 to be safe, could be set lower
x_1 <- seq(0, 1, length=1000)
x_2 <- seq(0, 1, length=1000)
z <- outer(x_1, x_2, FUN=f)
contour(x_1, x_2, z, levels=0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Same thing using ggplot:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)   # for melt(...)
## same as first response
x <- seq(0,10,length=1000)
y <- seq(-10,10, length=1000)
z <- outer(x,y,FUN=f)
# need this extra step 
gg <- melt(z, value.name="z",varnames=c("X","Y"))
# creates the plot
ggplot(gg) + stat_contour(aes(x=X, y=Y, z=z), breaks=0)
```

[image]